# Search pattern from tag and inserting it to next line by using sed or awk

Tags: command-line, awk, sed

I have several text files that I need to modify.
They look like as:

```
Tag: Brown
Chair
Pencil
Tag: Red
Apple
Shirt
Pant
         # <--- some files have one or more (about less than five) blank line(s)
Tag: Black
Wall
```

I would like to format it by taking words after "Tag:" as variable, inserting to next line until it meet other "Tag:".
The lines between "Tag:" may varies. So here output format example:

```
Brown Chair and Chairs
Brown Pencil and Pencils
Red Apple and Apples
Red Shirt and Shirts
Red Pant and Pants
         # <--- blank line(s) retain BLANK(s)
Black Wall and Walls
```

As I take a look and modify some sample at  http://sed.sourceforge.net/ but still no success.

```
sed ':loop; $!N; /^Tag:/h; n; /^Tag:/!b next; t loop; :next; x; p; x'
```

Thank you.

****Update****

As @jaypal suggestion and looking "carefully" at each text file, I'm adding "blank line(s)" scenario.

Comment: So if the file has `Tag: White` followed by `Mouse`, do you get `White Mouse and Mouses`? Or does some magic create `White Mice`?

Comment: Umm, I need logic for duplicating word at the following line after "Tag:", just in case using backreference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My attempt with sed (without loops, branches or backreferences, I like things simple):

```
sed '/Tag:/{s/Tag: //;h;d;};G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1 and \1s/'
```

**EDIT:**

To preserve blank lines:

```
sed '/Tag:/{s/Tag: //;h;d;};/./{G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1 and \1s/;}'
```

Comment: Nice and you kept BSD variant happy too with `;` before `}`. +1

Comment: Hmm, I just found that some of files having blank line(s). I try to modify:
    sed '/Tag:/{s/Tag: //;h;d;};G;s/\(.*[a-zA-Z]\)\n\(.*[a-zA-Z]\)/\2 \1 and \1s/'
but making it's result worse.

Comment: @JoCM: And what do you want the tool to do with a blank line? Print it? Delete it?

Comment: @Beta: I need to keep it as BLANK; as for record coresponding to other file. Thank you for remind me.

Comment: @JoCM You should update your question to include some data that truly represents your real data. It allows for quick testing of edge cases.

Comment: @JoCM Thanks for the edit. You can now consider accepting an answer which ever helped you the most. You can do so by clicking on the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: @EdMorton: Really? It worked when I tested it, and JoCM was satisfied. But my "blank" lines were empty-- do your "blank" lines contain whitespace?

Comment: Just for clarification: @Ed Morton, I remember that I have run other sed script to trim out ALL leading AND trailing whitespace(s) for all data files; saved with codepage 1252-ANSI and WIN_CRLF end-of-line format, therefore I have not seen problem yet.
By using [Paolo Bonzini's sed for windows] (http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/ssed/), I'm doing retest Beta sample script with blank line that TRULLY blank and other blank line contains whitespace(s) with WIN_CRLF or LINUX_LF end-of-line (use cp 1252-ANSI only).
The result is same as yours.

Comment: ...continue..., so IF blank line contains whitespace(s) in input file (whatever WIN_CRLF or LINUX_LF) will produce error output. I might personaly modify @Beta script with   ` sed '/Tag:/{s/Tag: //;h;d;};/[a-zA-Z]/{G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1 and \1s/;}' `.  
@Beta: for avoiding misleading, would you please editing your answer? Thank you all.

Comment: @EdMorton: I can't reproduce your error, but I'm curious to know why it's happening.

Comment: My mistake, turned out there was a single blank char in the first of the 2 blank lines. Once I removed that, your 2nd sed script did produce the expected output. Sorry for the noise!

Answer (score 2):

The following code deals with the most trivial of pluralisations (as in your example):

```
awk '/^Tag:/ {c=$2; next} {print c, $1, "and", $1"s"}' file
```

If the pattern matches, save the second field to `c` and skip to the next line. Otherwise, print the first word on the line with the simple pluralisation.

For something a bit more upmarket that is capable of pluralising a wider range of words, you could use the [`Lingua::EN::Inflect`](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Lingua-EN-Inflect-1.895/lib/Lingua/EN/Inflect.pm) Perl module:

```
perl -MLingua::EN::Inflect=PL -lane 'if(@F==2){$c=$F[1]}else{print "@{[$c,$_,q/and/,PL $_]}"}' file
```

Use `-a` to enable auto-split mode. If there are two fields, save the second one to `$c` (you could also do this using regex, I just fancied some variety). Otherwise, print the list. Using the `@{[ ]}` and wrapping in double quotes uses the built-in variable `$"` to join the list, which is a space by default.

Testing it out:

```
$ cat file
Tag: Brown
Chair
Pencil
Tag: Red
Apple
Shirt
Pant
Tag: White
Mouse
$ perl -MLingua::EN::Inflect=PL -lane 'if(@F==2){$c=$F[1]}else{print "@{[$c,$_,q/and/,PL $_]}"}' file
Brown Chair and Chairs
Brown Pencil and Pencils
Red Apple and Apples
Red Shirt and Shirts
Red Pant and Pants
White Mouse and Mice
```

Comment: Yea the perl module looks nice. Too bad I already upvoted! `;)`

Comment: @Tom Fenech, it works. Thank you for code and it's explanations. Plus additional new knowledge about "Lingua::EN::Inflect Perl module" for future references.
As my jobs occasionaly have to do with text parsing, I should take Perl language course; but too bad, I'm such as a slow learner 8-(

Answer (score 0):

Given an input file as posted in the question and with 2 blank lines:

```
$ awk '/^Tag:/{tag=$2; next} {print (NF ? tag " " $0 " and " $0 "s" : $0)}' file
Brown Chair and Chairs
Brown Pencil and Pencils
Red Apple and Apples
Red Shirt and Shirts
Red Pant and Pants


Black Wall and Walls
```

Comment: I don't get that error with the version of sed in Darwin 11.4.2. If you're fluent in sed, could you prepare a minimal complete example?